# how do you create tags like stackoverflow with text styling

Tags: css, input, styles

I was wondering how you can create css styling inside an input field such as stackoverflow's tagging system?

When you click on a tag, the text will be styled. And also, when you click on the styled tag, it will be normal again. I guess my main concern is how to style text inside an input field?

Thanks!

Comment: You're not thinking out of the box. What might seem like a textbox, really isn't one. There's no way to style anything inside a textbox, while it's possible to make a div look like one. Some food for thought.

Comment: Can i ask how do you css the delete icon?

Comment: i looked up "updateable tags" in google, first result was: https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/tag-editor/demo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you: http://basdebie.com/jquery-plugins/jquery-tags-autosuggest-like-delicious-stackoverflow-facebook/

By looking at this code, you should be able to create something similar, or just use the plugin.

Answer (score 8):

The tags are not input fields, they are links! On SO, the tags use the following styles:

```
.post-tag {
    color: #3E6D8E;
    background-color: #E0EAF1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #3E6D8E;
    border-right: 1px solid #7F9FB6;
    padding: 3px 4px 3px 4px;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 90%;
    line-height: 2.4;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

a.post-tag:hover {
    background-color: #3E6D8E;
    color: #E0EAF1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #37607D;
    border-right: 1px solid #37607D;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: and how can create a system that when user press <space>, then your style be apply ? (using js or jquery) (exactly like stackoverflow)

Answer (score 4):

Only the bit you type in is an input, the other tags are just styled `a` elements. When you hit return, the input moves right and gets shorter, and the value is copied and a new `a` element is created.

The text in the input isn't styled.